# Does every modern car have an evap vent valve?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank, evap, fuel-line, fuel-filter

My car has all the evap system, canister, and solenoid valve but as I am seeing on internet, people have [a] solenoid valve on their outlet vent on canister too which open and close by ECU to let the excessive vapor escape.

My car doesn't have that and I am having problem with my car [building] air pressure in the fuel tank.

I am really confused, so that means my gas tank itself has a vent line on it and it is connected to the fuel inlet hose and it evaporates the excessive vapor from there? It doesn't make any sense.

[image: this is the picture from what i understand]

---

### From Comments

In this question I am trying to find out why some cars have vent solenoid valve with their canister and what happens when some don't have that, how do they vent the vapor out then.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/53919/10976

Comment: No sir, in this question i am trying to find out why some cars have vent solenoid valve with their canister and what happens when some don't have that, how do they vent the vapor out then.

Comment: Show us a detailed diagram of the evaporator system as fitted to your car then we can see what components are where and which may be causing the problem.

Comment: @SolarMike - He's not asking about "his car". This is a generalized question revolving around the EVAP system.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the second paragraph specifically mentions his car and its problem so....

Comment: There is always a valve. Whether or not it is integrated into the canister depends on who designed it and how much they wanted to charge for replacement parts.

Comment: @DavidLively no there is no solenoid valve on vent there is no solenoid valve other than purge valve.

Comment: @SolarMike i haver attached the diagram please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: There is **always** a valve. It may be up on the cylinder head, it may be on top of the gas tank, but every semi-modern four-stroke engine sold in a country with any kind of emissions requirements has a valve.

Comment: And by "on the cylinder head," I mean near the throttle body. They're typically connected to the intake manifold or throttle body.

Comment: @DavidLively are you talking about the purge solenoid valve?

Comment: Whats the YMM of your car maybe someone can confirm through SI whether yours is supposed to or not. @DavidLively is right basically any car with emissions standards from the mid nineties on has one.

Comment: You are not having a problem with "building air pressure in the fuel tank", you have some other issue. Why don't you explain the symptoms?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, pressure that develops during filling the gas tank is relieved by venting to the atmosphere via the filler tube (some locales require filler nozzles to be equipped with vapor recovery, in that case the fill nozzle seals to the filler neck and vapors are sucked/pumped back into the filling station tank).

The evap system is designed to scavenge vapors that might otherwise occasionally be vented to atmosphere through the filler tube when you open the gas cap. Filling up is usually preceded by a period of driving, when the system could operate and burn the vapor in the engine via the **purge valve**, usually solenoid operated and controlled by the ECU. The system is not designed to relieve pressure to prevent pressure-related problems, because the vapor pressure of the fuel is minimal and *not a problem*.

Think about it, if malfunction of the evap purge/vent could cause pressure problems in the fuel system *what happens for days on end when your car sits and fuel vapor pressure develops in the system?* The only **"vent"** is the purge vent to the engine, any other vent would defeat the purpose of an evap recovery system.

*Note- not an expert, just using the little I know combined with common sense.*

Comment: Key off engine off the vent solenoid is always open. the only reason there’s a solenoid is to check the system integrity. That doesn’t mean that the vent line doesn’t allow excess vapor to escape out the vent. When the vent solenoid is stuck closed or the line is obstructed there are literally problems with excess pressure in the system.

Comment: @Ben ...KOEO purge open makes sense. I will downvote my own answer, thanks. Curious though, where would fuel vapor go? Out the exhaust valves to atmosphere? That would seem contradictory to the purpose.

Comment: The canister is supposed to capture fuel vapor In normal operation. Excess vapor or a canister that isn’t doing it’s job will vent to atmosphere. Barring a restriction in the canister or vent line